# Cookie not persisting in Laravel 4 with Sentry

Tags: php, apache, laravel, cookies, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 and Sentry for Authentication.

I'm facing a problem that cookie for remember is not persisting a day, The expiry is set to be 1 year ahead from NOW. Even the cookie is present in browser but somehow not getting on server.

I tried to implement my own custom cookie based remember me, but same issues persists.

Anything that might be causing this issue.

Comment: Does the server storage folder having enough permissions ?

Comment: That was a nightmare for me. I used a ton of hacky work arounds and finally only solved it by upgrading to Laravel 5